# PowerShell: How to reliably send emails

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-7.0

According to the cmdlet [help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7), `Send-MailMessage` is no longer recommended for sending email, especially to SMTP servers.

The .NET Platform Compatibility Note, which the documentation leads to, says to use the *MailKit* .NET library. Upon examining that library's documentation, it found that it's primarily for use with C#. However I want to send email directly from  PowerShell.

Are there other options for carrying out this task?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from loading MailKit into PowerShell and calling its methods, e.g. https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell/

Comment: What is your use case? Based on the deprecation notice, you definitely shouldn't use `Send-MailMessage` to submit messages _over the internet_, but if you're sending via a local relay or an MTA in the same local network, then... meh, who cares :)

Comment: No, for my use case I would be particularly concerned about security, hence the question. I should have made that more clear, sorry.

Comment: You can easily find Powershell examples involving MailKit ( https://adamtheautomator.com/how-to-send-email-securely-with-powershell/ ) or you can use an existing module from Powershell Gallery that uses MailKit ( https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Send-MailKitMessage/ ). I make no claims about the quality or utility or appropriateness those examples. I'm merely showing that they're not hard to find.

Comment: Thank you @IanKemp for the useful generic solution.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks for showing me those.